# Using model objects created using different scikit-learn versions

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a project where I would like to make predictions using previously created model objects. The model objects where both build using scikit-learn but on different library versions (0.22.1 and 1.2.0). My questions are as follows:

- I have always been under the assumption that if you are going to make predictions with a model object you should have an environment that matches the environment that the object was built on. Is this truly the case? (I often get trying to unpickle estimator from version warning)
- What would be the safest way to score predictions in the same notebook/environment using these two models? I would prefer to not rebuild the model. Would converting the scikit-learn/joblib saved objects to ONNX be a way around this?